# How to input value to matrix by considering speciall another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

One possible solution is the following. Note that I took the freedom to assign meaningful names to your variables, as names such as `A` and `Start Time A` (which is not even a valid Matlab identifier) are really easy to confuse. Also you can see that your matrices
`C` and `Start Time C` are redundant because all the information is already encoded in `A`,
`B` and `Start Time A`.

```
% The values to put in the result matrix.
value = [5 6 7;
         7 5 6];
% Column index where each sequence starts in the result matrix.
start = [2 3 7;
         1 6 8];
% The length of each sequence, i.e. how often to put the value into the result.
count = [1 2 3;
         3 1 2];

% Determine the longest row. Note: At this place you could also check, if all 
% rows are of the same length. The current implementation pads shorter rows with
% zeros.
max_row_length = max(start(:, end) + count(:, end) - 1);

% Allocate an output matrix filled with zeros. This avoids inserting sequences
% of zeros afterwards.
result = zeros(size(start, 1), max_row_length);

% Finally fill the matrix using a double loop.
for row = 1 : size(start, 1)
    for column = 1 : size(start, 2)
        s = start(row, column);
        c = count(row, column);
        v = value(row, column);
        result(row, s : s + c - 1) = v;
    end
end
```

The `result` is

```
result =

     0     5     6     6     0     0     7     7     7
     7     7     7     0     0     5     0     6     6
```

as requested.

How can I modify the above code for solving 3D matrix.

Example : size of third dimension is 2.
Matrix Value

```
value(:,:,1) = [5 6 7;
                7 5 6];
value(:,:,2) = [6 5 7;
                6 7 5];

start(:,:,1) = [2 3 7;
                1 6 8];
start(:,:,2) = [1 5 6;
                2 5 9];

count(:,:,1) = [1 2 3;
                3 1 2];
count(:,:,2) = [2 1 3;
                2 3 1];
```

I wish my result matrix is

```
result(:,:,1) =[0 5 6 6 0 0 7 7 7;
                7 7 7 0 0 5 0 6 6]
result(:,:,2) =[6 6 0 0 5 7 7 7 0;
                0 6 6 0 7 7 7 0 5]
```

How to make code to make a result. thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would be using "depth" information to place elements into a 3D matrix?  It's pretty straight forward working with 2D here.  I'm mainly wondering how you'd be presented the information to know where to place the elements in 3D and what an example result would be.  I'm thinking it might just be as simple as adding another inner loop that would cycle through your 3rd dimension.

Comment: @BenA. Mr see my updated question. I gave example that size of third dimension is 2. but actually I have more than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea of how to tackle the question if it doesn't fully answer it.  I haven't tested the code that I'm putting in here, just simply modifying what you're providing to the best of my knowledge.

```
result = zeros(size(start, 1), max_row_length, size(start,3)); 

% Finally fill the matrix using a double loop. 
for depth = 1:size(start,3)
    for row = 1 : size(start, 1) 
        for column = 1 : size(start, 2) 
            s = start(row, column, depth); 
            c = count(row, column, depth); 
            v = value(row, column, depth); 
            result(row, s : s + c - 1, depth) = v; 
        end 
    end 
end
```